# Cannot connect to redis using jedis

Tags: redis, jedis

Redis version: `3.2.0`
Jedis version: `2.8.1`

Below is my java code for connecting to redis:

```
public class TestRedis {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String host = args[0];
        int port = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        try (Jedis jedis = new Jedis(host, port)) {
            System.out.println("Connected to jedis " + jedis.ping());
        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I am running this program on the machine where redis is installed. The public IP address is `192.168.1.57`

If I provide host="localhost" and port = "6379" as arguments, then I can successfully connect with redis.

However, If I give host="192.168.1.57" and port = "6379" in arguments, I end up with the following exception:

```
redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.connect(Connection.java:164)
    at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryClient.connect(BinaryClient.java:80)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.sendCommand(Connection.java:100)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.sendCommand(Connection.java:95)
    at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryClient.ping(BinaryClient.java:93)
    at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedis.ping(BinaryJedis.java:105)
    at TestRedis.main(TestRedis.java:14)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.connect(Connection.java:158)
    ... 6 more
```

Please help...

Comment: In my case, I had to open an SSH tunnel into the remote host to resolve the issue

Answer (score 8):

There are a few settings that would affect this: **bind** and **protected-mode**. They work together to provide a baseline of security with new installs.

Find the following in your `redis.conf` file and comment it out:

```
bind 127.0.0.1
```

By adding a `#` in front of it:

```
# bind 127.0.0.1
```

Or, if you would rather not comment it out, you can also add the IP of your `eth0`/`em1` interface to it, like this:

```
bind 127.0.0.1 192.168.1.57
```

Also, unless you're using password security, you'll also have to turn off protected mode by changing:

```
protected-mode yes
```

To:

```
protected-mode no
```

Make sure that you read the relevant documentation and understand the security implications of both of these changes.

After making these changes, restart redis.

Comment: I implemented all of these suggestions to no avail.